# TypeScript components内でmap()を使用するとエラーが出る。

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-jsx, next.js

`<span>`タグに `topic` を代入して出力するコンポーネントを作成したいのですが、 `(property) topicList: string[] ',' expected.ts(1005)` と出て `.map` が使えないみたいな表示がされます。なぜこのようになるのか分からないです。コードを見て頂けないでしょうか？

```
//topicListには["javascript", "初心者", "作業ログ"]と文字列の配列が渡される予定です。
export default function Topics({ topicList }: { topicList: string[] }) {
  return ({
      topicList.map(topic => {
        <span >{topic}</span>
      })
    }
  )
}
```

#### 追記

確か空のタグで囲ってないとダメだった気がしたので `<>` で囲ったけどエラーは改善されませんでした。
でもこれってコンポートだから呼び出し側でdivタグで囲まれていれば問題ない気がします。

```
export default function Topics({ topicList }: { topicList: string[] }) {
  return ({
    <>
      topicList.map(topic => {
        <span >{topic}</span>
      })
   </>
    }
  )
}
```

#### 追記2

エラーは取れたのですが、使用してもサイト側で思い通りに表示されない。

```
export default function Topics({ topicList }: { topicList: string[] }) {
  return (
    <>
      {
        topicList.map(topic => {
          <span >{topic}</span>
        })
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

＊＊呼び出し側**

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import { getPostsData } from '../lib/posts'
import { getSortedPostsData } from '../lib/posts'
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { Article } from '../types/Article'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import Date from '../components/date'
import Topics from '../components/topics'



const pattern = ["bg-blue", "bg-blue-light", "bg-gray", "bg-earth-light"]; 

function getColorClassFromIndex(index: number): string {
  return pattern[index % pattern.length];
}

export default function Home({ 
  sortedPostData
}: {
  sortedPostData: Article[]
}) {
  return (
    <Layout home>
      <div className="">
        <Head>
          <title>Hello</title>
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <ul>
          {sortedPostData.map(({ id, title, date, topics }, index) => (
            <li className={"h-44 " + getColorClassFromIndex(index)} key={id}>
              <Link href={`/posts/${id}`}>
                {title}
              </Link>
              <br />
              <small>
                <Topics topicList={topics} />
                <Date dateString={date} />
              </small>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const allPostsData = await getPostsData()
  const sortedPostData = await getSortedPostsData(allPostsData)
  return {
    props: {
      sortedPostData
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{}`が必要なのは、ReactElement 内でJavaScript(TypeScript)コードを記述する場合です。

`function Topics()` が返す値が `ReactElement[]` の場合、そもそも `{}` が不要ですので、以下の様に書いてください。

- `.map()` に渡すアロー関数で値を返してください
- `key` prop を設定してください

  - [リストと key – React#Key](https://ja.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

```
export default function Topics({ topicList }: { topicList: string[] }) {
  return topicList.map(topic => (<span key={topic}>{topic}</span>));
}
```

返す値が `ReactElement` の場合は、以下の様になります。

```
export default function Topics({ topicList }: { topicList: string[] }) {
  // ReactElement内 (<> </> 内) にコードを書いているので、 {} が必要
  return (
    <>
      {topicList.map(topic => (<span key={topic}>{topic}</span>))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: 上記の `ReactElement`の方をコピペしたらちゃんと動作しました。

Comment: この `key`というのも設定しないとしっかりレンダーされないんですね。

Comment: 表示されなかった理由は、先日の回答でも書いた通り `.map()`に渡していたアロー関数が `(topic) => {}`になっていてvoid(undefined)の配列が返っていたせいだと思います。 `key` が設定されていなくてもレンダリング自体はされますが、要素が追加削除されるケースなどにおいて問題となることがあります。[リストと key – React#Key](https://ja.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: `.map(() => {})` これだと使い方として違うという事でしょうか？同じミスをすいません。

Comment: `.map(() => { return (value); })` か `.map(() => (value))` で書いてください。思い切って今後 **`.map()` に渡す関数で** `{}` を使わない、のも良いかもしれません。

Comment: `.map(() => {return()}` ありがとうございます。これで出来ました。

Comment: すいません。 `key`なんですけどこれって`topic` だと同じ文字列が記事間で複数ある場合、被ってしまうと思うのですが兄弟間になるのでしょうか？兄弟要素の中で一意であれば良いと公式には書いてありました。

Comment: ここでの文脈で言えば、同じ記事内(1つの記事内)でtopicが被ってなければ大丈夫です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。